# printing parallel over ethernet cable

Tags: printing, cat5

I have a bit of an interesting challenge :)
I have a machine with a parallel printer output, i want it to be able to print instead to a printer in a different room and i know that parallel isnt great over big distances.
i found this:

[http://www.amazon.com/over-Cat5-Extension-Cable-Adapter/dp/B002WJ9S6Y%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAINHICTCYYZGJWT4Q%26tag%3Dusbprintercables.net-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB002WJ9S6Y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002WJ9S6Y)

which will let me connect over cat5, but its usb to cat 5.
my machine can only output on parallel (its not a computer)
so what i was thinking of getting is a parallel(f) to usb and usb to parallel (M) for either side

i.e. machine -> parallel -> usb -> cat5 -> usb -> parallel ->printer

just seems a bit messy :)
suggestions?

another thing i would like to try is to get rid of the old school parallel printer and instead use a network based multi function. would this be possible?

i.e. machine -> parallel ->usb -> cat5 -> ethernet print server - > network printer

this might be rougher because the machine cannot "know" that we are using a network printer. it can ONLY print to LPT1

Thanks!

Comment: There is to the best of my knowledge, no such thing as USB > Parallel. Interesting problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel to usb adapters do exists. Here is a picture of one from Belkin:

[image: belkin_adapter]

I'm not sure if the combination of extender+adapter would work, but given the price of both, the total cost of the experimentation would be around 20USD.

This is much cheaper than an arduino + ethernet shield, without the programming/electronic hassle.

[Google Shopping link](http://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20parallel&tbm=shop)

Comment: That's for plugging an LPT printer *into* USB, I'm not sure how you'll get the same usb-converted LPT back into standard LPT. (You could however definately try converting that USB into CAT5 using a converter and back again)

Comment: well, I don't know why it wouldn't work, one just has to adapt the female db25 and the male centronics, but signals are the same...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how good your electronics skill is, but parallel is a *very* simple protocol. It would not be inconcievable to use something like an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) to pick up the pin outputs, transfer them over ethernet to a 2nd Arduino that then outputs them at the destination device.

Paralell is two-way though, so I don't know how synchronising the send/receive would work, but with low enough latency (parallel is super slow, so I'm *guessing* ethernet latency might be OK) it should be possible to emulate a direct-attached device.

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for (as far as Google is concerned) is "parallel extender" or "[parallel line extender](http://www.google.com/search?q=parallel%20line%20extender)". There's an ATEN one that runs around $40 currently, and claims to run over regular telephone cable.